# C# - create and write HTML file with variables

Tags: c#, html

Basiclly I'm trying to create an HTML, I already have it written but I want the user to be able to put some text on the textboxes and saving it into strings and use later when creating the HTML file.

I tried playing abit with StreamWriter but I don't think that will be the best idea.
Also I want it to open on the default web browser , or just on IE if it's easier after the file is created.

I really need help as I'm struggling especially with the creating part.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Give us code and what exactly you want. You can use Html parser !

Comment: It's usually a good idea to provide your code, so that people have something to work with when showing you what to do. That'll save them time, and the answer will be more personalized to your needs.

Comment: You could save your content, the one entered into textboxes, in a SQL database and retrieve the content later when you need it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do this without external libraries.

Set up your HTML file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<title>{MY_TITLE}</title>
</header>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Then edit and save the HTML from C#:

```
const string fileName = "Foobar.html";

//Read HTML from file
var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

//Replace all values in the HTML
content = content.Replace("{MY_TITLE}", titleTextBox.Text);

//Write new HTML string to file
File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);

//Show it in the default application for handling .html files
Process.Start(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the HTML you want to export (just not customized), you could manually add format strings to it (like `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`) where you want to substitute text from your app, then embed it as a resource, load it in at runtime, substitute the TextBox text using `string.Format`, and finally write it out again.  This is admittedly a really fragile way to do it, as you need to make sure the number of parameters agrees between the resource file and your call to `string.Format`.  In fact, this is a horrible way to do it.  Actually, you should do it the way @EmilePels suggests, which is basically a less fragile version of this answer.